# Converting String to vector of Integers

Tags: c++, stdvector

FizzBuzz program. The user enters numbers separated by a comma. The program reads input and lets the computer know if divisible by 3, 5 or both. When the user enters 15,5,30, the program will only output the first number, 15 and stops there. What am I doing wrong?

```
void processVector(vector<int> intVector)
{
    bool loop;
    for (int i = 0; i < intVector.size(); i++)
    {
        loop = true;
    }
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Welcome to the FizzBuzz program!" << endl;

    cout << "This program will check if the number you enter is divisable by 
          3, 5, or both." << endl;


    cout << "Please enter an array of numbers separated by a comma like so, 
          5,10,15" << endl;
    cin >> userArray;

    vector<int> loadVector(string inputString);
    istringstream iss(userArray);
    vector <int> v;

    int i;

    while (iss >> i);
    {
        v.push_back(i);
        if (iss.peek() == ',')
            iss.ignore();


        if (i % 15 == 0)
        {
            cout << "Number " << i << " - FizzBuzz!" << endl;

        }
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            cout << "Number " << i << " Fizz!" << endl;

        }

        else if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            cout << "Number " << i << " Buzz!" << endl;

        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Number entered is not divisable by 3 or 5." << endl;       
        }
    }

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Pretty sure among the things you're doing wrong are: Failure to include header files, failure to declare `userArray`.  While loop with an empty body.  Calling `system()` when you don't need it.  Declaring `loadVector()` but never calling it.  Defining `processVector()` but never using it in any way.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, Thank you, Ben, I do have the header files, I didn't copy the code in its entirety in the post. Header files I have are .... 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>......
I will look over the rest. Again thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    std::cout << "Please enter your numbers seperated by a comma (5, 3, 5, 98, 278, 42): ";

    std::string userString;
    std::getline(std::cin, userString);
    std::vector<int> numberV;

    size_t j = 0; // beginning of number
    for(size_t i = 0; i < userString.size(); i++){
        if((userString[i] == ',') || (i == userString.size() -1)){ // could also use strncmp
            numberV.push_back(std::stoi(userString.substr(j, i))); // stoi stands for string to int, and .substr(start, end) creates a new string at the start location and ending at the end location
            j = i + 1;

        }
    }

    for(size_t n = 0; n < numberV.size(); n++){
        std::cout << numberV[n] << std::endl;
    }

    return(0);
```

}

This should give you a method to solve the problem (without handling the fizzbuzz part of your program) that I personally find simpler.

The basic form for using functions is:

```
<return type> <function_name(<inputs)>{
    stuff
};
```

So, a basic function that takes a string and returns a vector (what you are wanting) would be:

```
std::vector myStringToVector(std::string inputString){
    std::vector V;
    // your code (see the prior example for one method of doing this)
    return(V);
};
```

It also looks like they want a separate function for outputting your vector values, this could look something like:

```
void myVectorPrint(std::vector inputVector){
    // your code (see prior example for a method of printing out a vector)
};
```

Comment: @Aarin Covrig Thank you, that does look simpler, however, per the instructions I have to include two functions per instructions like so 
  Create a function that will convert the input string into a vector of integers.  The function must look like this:
 
vector<int> loadVector(string inputString)
 
Write another function that will output the results of processing the vector of integers against the FizzBuzz rules defined in week 2.  Display the output according to the rules in the Week 2 assignment. The function should look like this:
 
void processVector(vector<int> intVector)

Comment: You can easily modify the code to work in functions, you can take the code starting with the definition of 'j' and ending at the end of the for loop and put it into a function that takes a string and returns a vector.  I believe your process vector function needs work also, it looks like you are supposed to bout your print statements inside it.

Comment: I've added a bit more info and some pseudo code, you can use this with the rest of the provided code to solve your problem, since this is homework I'm not going to solve it completely for you (but, all you really need to do is pull it apart and fit it into those couple functions to meet your instructors requirements).

Comment: Thank you @ Aaron I am working on it and will post the end result. I thought I only had to call the functions by name in the main but nope. I am completely new and looking at the different codes helps me to see how it works. Hopefully, I can get it done tonight after work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Aaron for the help. Here is the finished code and it works great! 
I had to take a little more time researching a few things and trying to understand which order and what to put where in terms of the functions and how to call them. I appreciate all the help as I said I am a noob.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


vector<int> loadVector(string inputString)
{
stringstream ss(inputString);
vector <int> numberV;

int n;

size_t j = 0; // beginning of number
for (size_t n = 0; n < inputString.size(); n++) 
{
    if ((inputString[n] == ',') || (n == inputString.size() - 1)) 
    { 
        numberV.push_back(std::stoi(inputString.substr(j, n))); 
        j = n + 1;

    }

}


return numberV;
}
void processVector(vector<int> intVector)
{
for (int i = 0; i < intVector.size(); i++)
{
    int n = intVector.at(i);
    if (n % 15 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Number " << n << " - FizzBuzz!" << endl;
    }
    else if (n % 3 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Number " << n << " Fizz!" << endl;
    }

    else if (n % 5 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Number " << n << " Buzz!" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Number entered is not divisable by 3 or 5." << endl;
    }
}
}

int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to the FizzBuzz program." << endl
    << "Please enter an array of numbers separated by comma's (5, 10, 15)" 
    << endl;

string inputString;
getline(cin, inputString); 

try
{
    vector<int> intVector = loadVector(inputString);
    processVector(intVector);
}
catch (const exception& e)
{
    cout << "Exception caught: '" << e.what() << "'!;" << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```